# "Index was outside the bounds of the array" error in Array class object

Tags: arrays, sharepoint-2013, indexoutofboundsexception

I want to store all user profile multiple string value to the Array object. My code is:

```
                    if (upm != null)
                    {
                        for (int i = 0; i < otherMembers.Count; i++)
                        {
                            UserProfile user = upm.GetUserProfile(otherMembers[i]);


                            int j = 0;
                            if (user[FieldNames.OtherDepartment].Count != 0)
                            {

                                UserProfileValueCollection valueCollection = user[FieldNames.OtherDepartment];
                                Array otherDepartments = Array.CreateInstance(typeof(string), user[FieldNames.OtherDepartment].Count);
                                foreach (object value in valueCollection)
                                {
                                    otherDepartments.SetValue(value.ToString(), j);
                                    j++;
                                }

                                j = otherDepartments.Length;
                                otherDepartments.SetValue(fieldValue.Label, j);

                                user[FieldNames.OtherDepartment].Value = otherDepartments;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                user[FieldNames.OtherDepartment].Value = fieldValue.Label;
                            }
                            //user[FieldNames.OtherDepartment].Value += fieldValue.Label;
                            user.Commit();
                        }
                    }
```

I am getting the error at the line: `otherDepartments.SetValue(fieldValue.Label, j);` outside the `forech()` loop. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

You have an off by one error in your code.

Try to change this:

```
j = otherDepartments.Length;
```

Into this:

```
j = otherDepartments.Length-1;
```

Since array indexing typically starts at 0, so the last element is `length-1`.